# about the file path

Tags: directory, filepath

There are relative path and absolute path of the a file. But some of the writings confuse me sometimes:

```
/a/b/c.php   //relative document root
./a/b/c.php  //what does this mean? equals to '/a/b/c.php' or a/b/c.php?

a/b/c.php    //relative to current directory
../a/b/c.php  //parent folder relative to current directory
/../a/b/c.php  //what does this mean? parent folder of document root?
```

Are there other ways of writing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some basic directory symbol for you:

- `.` (dot) is your current directory
- `..` (double-dot) is the parent of your current directory
- `~` (tilde) is your home directory.
- `/` (slash) if it present at first character, it usually is called root directory.

These all came from linux / unix terminology (**CMIIW** here).

Now, let's take a look at the implementation:

- Let's say, you are on `/home/username/`
- if you write something like this, the result is:

  1. `./wwwroot/somedir/` => `/home/username/wwwroot/somedir/`
  2. `../wwwroot/somedir/` => `/home/wwwroot/somedir/`
  3. `/../wwwroot/somedir/` => `/wwwroot/somedir`

You might get confused on example #3. If you put `/` in front of path info, it mean you are at the root directory. Therefore, if you write `/../somedir/` it mean, you are pointing to /somedir/. Why? because root directory doesn't have parent.

Answer (score 2):

. = current directory. So `./a/b/c.php` would be equivalent to `a/b/c.php`.

`/../a/b/c.php` means go to the root directory, then up one, then directory `a`, then directory `b`, then `c.php`.

Comment: "/../a/b/c.php means go to the root directory, then up one" up one means goto the parent folder of the root directory?

Comment: Yes, go to the parent of the root, then folder a, then folder b, then file c.php